# Cannot save 'AssemblyInfo.cs' as it is not open in the editor

Tags: c#, com

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will add an attribute to a project's AssemblyInfo.cs, but getting this exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot save 'C:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' as it is not open in the editor.'
```

`ClassLibrary1` contains `AssemblyInfo.cs` which I'm trying to edit.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
I used ProjectItem.Open(String) Method to force `AssemblyInfo.cs` to open.